# Single line If statement giving compilation errors while trying to declare a variable inside the If block. What is the reason?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

A single line If statement is giving compilation errors while trying to declare and assign a variable inside the single lined If block.
Here's the code:

```
if(true)
    String msg = "Hellow";
```

[image]

But once I declare the variable outside the If block, it doesn't complain any more.
Here's the code:

```
String msg;
if(true)
    msg = "Hellow";
```

Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: even you set if to be always executed java compiler only allows you to access the variable outside the if statement, if you also add an else block to it, so there is never a chance for the variable to not be initialized

Comment: Interesting one! I suppose that no one would ever want to do that anyway (because you'll never get to use `msg`)

Comment: @Appleman are you using "msg" variable anywhere else like after declaring String msg="Hellow";. If then please check its inside if block or outside.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi No I am not using the 'msg' variable name anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we initialize a variable in a single lined if block, we cannot use it anywhere else in the program, thats the reason for compilation error. Same reason why unreachable code is a compilation error in java in case we put any code after return statement.

The compilation error depends on the scope of the variable. If the variable scope is increased to multiple lines as in the below code section, declaration is possible.

```
if(true)
    for(int a=0;a<5;a++)
        System.out.println(a);   //Compiles Fine
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a JLS place for this describing that the contents can only be a field assignment / method call / other such operation (i.e. something else than a variable declaration), but as is obvious if it compiled it would be a NOOP.

Declaring a variable with scope of a single line isn't useful, so this would mean a programming error. The error message doesn't make it very clear, but the basic reason is "you're not allowed to do that, because the syntax says so".

By providing the *possibility* of a broader scope with braces, there is no error.

```
if(true) {
    String foo = "bar"; // Compiles fine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was very interesting .
I found some thing i have read before

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html

```
If Then Statement:
            if ( Expression ) Statement where   String msg = "Hellow"; is not statement.
```

So it doesn't work.

and local variable declaration is a statement so it doesn't give error.
so this works

String msg;
if(true)
    msg = "Hellow";

Answer (score 0):

To declare a variable within an if statement, it needs to be within braces {}.
So This should work:

```
if(true) {
    String msg = "Hellow";
}
```

However, this variable cannot be accessed outside that if block.